# Webpage hover mouse on element to invoke API

Tags: javascript, html, grafana

I am currently showing 5 top consuming AWS RDS instance in a dashboard in Grafana. Then I want to hover my mouse on top of each of those instances, which should invoke API post call which will bring back additional details about that instance. Additional details about those like instance type should pop up (i.e. db engine type details, endpoint). Can it be achieved using javascript & HTML? My API is written in python lambda. Not much worked on HTML or JS,so any help will be appreciated

[image]

Here when I hover mouse on each category its showing the value for error/info/warning. Instead I want to invoke POST API & get additional details of my choice & display

Grafana link: https://play.grafana.org/d/6NmftOxZz/logs-panel?orgId=1
use Polystat visualization there

Answer (score 0):

get the element by DOM
bind the hover callback on JS
invoke API this moment 
put the result data back to the target DOM